# C# form show and infinity loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

In one of my classes, I have got code:

```
    private static void Notify(string url, string author, string mess)
    {
        Toast slice = new Toast(100000, url, author, mess) { Height = 90 };
        slice.Show();
        return;
    }

    public void Job()
    {
        Notify("http://google.com", "username", "hi all");
        while (true)
        {
            if (Run() == false)
                break;
        }
        /* .... */
    }
```

Notify function is displays a small box with my text. it works well, but if it comes after a loop, then the program hangs. ie if after `Notify("http://google.com", "username", "hi all");` add `return;`, program will not hang.

I tried to make this function in another thread, but then for some reason it does not work properly and displays a "white list". What am I doing wrong and what you can do in this situation? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You can only manipulate UI elements from the main UI thread... and you should never implement an endless loop on that same thread, because it will lock up your UI.

Comment: This loop is running in another thread.

Comment: Ummm... that's not what your question said; *I tried to make this function in another thread, but then for some reason it does not work properly and displays a "white list"* And running the loop on the UI thread exactly explains what's happening.

Comment: Loop is running in another thread, but this loop will create "Toast" form. _I tried to make this function in another thread_ - i tried to create "toast" from another thread, than loop.

Comment: Go back to my original comment. It had two parts. The first part was: *You can only manipulate UI elements from the main UI thread*. By creating a UI element on another thread, you again broke the application. That thread will never trigger 'drawing' events, for example.

Comment: Ok, i created the variable "_loader", that contains main UI thread. In main UI thread, I created Notify function too. Now I call this function from thread with a loop: `_loader.Notify("http://google.com", "username", "hi all");`. That gives no result.

Comment: Then you are back to your loop being your problem. You simply do not need that loop. You could simply instead use `slide.ShowDialog()` to block other program activity until you close it.

Comment: Yes, program doesnt hang, but at the same time, on the screen may be several such windows (in the form of "Toast" is provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what's been said in the comments, I may have a solution for you.

First, be sure you are calling `Job()` from the main UI thread. For example, directly in a UI object Event Handler, or within a call to a UI object's `Invoke()` method.

Then I would change your code as follows:

```
private static void Notify(string url, string author, string mess)
{
    using(Toast slice = new Toast(100000, url, author, mess) { Height = 90 })
    {
        slice.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public void Job()
{
    Notify("http://google.com", "username", "hi all");
}
```

Note that I remove the loop entirely, and I use `ShowDialog()` to prevent further interaction with the program until the `slice` window is closed.

I've also put `slice` in a `using()` block, because it should have `Dispose()` called when you are done with it.

Comment: For multiple `Toast`, i do this: `new Thread(() => new ToastForm(100000, mess, url, author) { Height = 90 }.ShowDialog()).Start();}`

Comment: @Anton You haven't read a thing I've said, then. You are creating UI objects on new threads, and you are failing to `Dispose()` of UI objects.

Comment: `this.Close()` is fine, but it's not a good idea to `Dispose()` something from code within itself, as it's possible that could cause other members to be called, which would raise an `ObjectDisposedException`. You can instead externally define a handler for the `Form.FormClosed` event which disposes it. *But you still have to stop creating new threads for these*